# Semidefinite Matrix in LINGO

Tags: positive-semidefinite

Using LINGO, I need to enter the following block matrix as one of my constraints

$
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   1 & x^T \\
   x & X \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$

where x is an n by 1 column matrix and X is an n by n symmetric matrix. Then I need to fore M to be PSD one time and in another problem to be copositive. Does any one know how to do that using LINGO.